# Google App Engine - creating dummy records in a database

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to create some entries in my database, and then render them via jinja2.

The following is my execution flow:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([ ('/dummy', createDummy),('/', MainPage)],debug=True)
```

where createDummy is:

```
class createDummy(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        print("Hi! Let's post some data to db")
        book1 = BooksPost(bookname="abcd",
                          authorname="xyz")
        book1.put()
        self.redirect('/')**
```

However, it is not going into createDummy, but is directly going to the MainPage...what could be the possible reason?

Comment: how does your request look like?

Comment: Note that it's a _POST_ handler...